# Horizontal bar chart doesn't start at 0

Tags: ios, swift, ios-charts

[Sample Chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hDxVJ.png)

When I provide data for Bar Chart it appears with little offset. I thought about stacked Bar Chart, but it was wrong - that how I provide sample data for chart:

```
var barEntries = [BarChartDataEntry]()
barEntries.append(BarChartDataEntry(x: 0, y: 0))
barEntries.append(BarChartDataEntry(x: 4, y: 1))
barEntries.append(BarChartDataEntry(x: 8, y: 24))
barEntries.append(BarChartDataEntry(x: 12, y: 37))
barEntries.append(BarChartDataEntry(x: 16, y: 27))
barEntries.append(BarChartDataEntry(x: 20, y: 11))

let barDataSet = BarChartDataSet(values: barEntries, label: nil)
let barData = BarChartData(dataSet: barDataSet)
barData.barWidth = 4
barChartView.data = barData
```

All `barEntries` was created with `BarChartDataEntry` initializers for non-stacked bar. Now I have no idea why bar doesn't start at 0.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

try set `barChartView.leftAxis.axisMinimum = 0` or 'barChartView.rightAxis.axisMinimum = 0' or barChartView.xAxis.axisMinimum = 0. Check ChartsDemo.

Comment: Thanks, you're almost right.

To move all bars to zero, we need set both:

`barChartView.rightAxis.axisMinimum = 0.0`
`barChartView.leftAxis.axisMinimum = 0.0`

Answer (score 0):

initialise `barEntries` with `[BarChartDataEntry(x: 0, y: 0)]` rather than appending `BarChartDataEntry(x: 0, y: 0)`.

Comment: How that can help me? Nevertheless, I checked it out, it still appears with offset.

Comment: Update the link to your sample chart because it doesn't work so i can help you. Try be more specific on what you are trying to do.

Comment: It's strange, link is working, checked on several computers with different people. Here is direct link: https://i.stack.imgur.com/hDxVJ.png